# Rails 2 -- Pass parameter to wicked_pdf based on server os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, pdf-generation

I have a method

```
def welcome(*args)
  #....some code
end
```

Based on a situation I have to call this method sometimes as

```
welcome(arg1,arg2) {|block| #code}
```

but sometimes I want to call

```
welcome(arg1) {|block| #code}
```

the block part for both the calls is the same

Please Help me to DRY up this code and achieve the functionality

**EDIT**

**Sorry for not showing this earlier**

I am trying to implement wicked_pdf plugin into my rails app. It has following code

```
Open3.popen3(command_for_stdin_stdout,"b") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
      stdin.write(string)
      stdin.close
      pdf = stdout.read
      raise "PDF could not be generated!\n#{stderr.read}" if pdf.length == 0
      pdf
end
```

The second argument passed to the method i.e. "b" is required only if the server is running on windows, else there is no need of the parameter. When I tried to pass a blank value it doesn't generate a pdf. I tried doing this

```
Open3.popen3(command_for_stdin_stdout,(["i386-mingw32","mswin","win32","mingw","bccwin","cygwin"].include?(RUBY_PLATFORM) ? "b" : ""))
.......#rest of the code
```

Thanks

Comment: The current version of wicked_pdf makes stdin, stdout, & stderr binmode inside the open3 call, I'd be curious to see if that makes your patch no longer necessary.

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem! Block arguments get their own slot in a Ruby method, so it's perfectly safe to have your splatted arguments at the same time.

```
def welcome(*args)
  puts args.inspect
  yield
  #....some code
end

welcome "asdf", "asdf" do
  puts "uh-oh"
end

welcome "just one" do
  puts "still works?"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def welcome(arg1, arg2="default")
  ...
end
```

you can call it either way, and arg2 will be the default value if not set by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
welcome( :arg1 => arg1, :arg2 => arg2) {|blockety|block}
```

args ends up being

```
{:arg1 => arg1, :arg2 => arg2}
```

inside the welcome method. Then you grab them as you need them from the hash

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
open_options = [command_for_stdin_stdout, ("b" if ENV['OS'] == 'Windows_NT')].compact
Open3.popen3(*open_options) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  ...
end
```